# And Operator and Semi Colon

Tags: bash, shell

In Linux use use AND Operators and it is represented by (&). In commands we can either use (&&) or (;). So, does a semi Colon (;) is also called an AND Operator?

Comment: Most likely duplicate of: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/237982

Comment: So, a semi-colon is called a "List Terminator"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, a semicolon is not a boolean operator. It is however, just like `&&`, `&`, and newlines, a command terminator, marking the end of a command.

The difference between

```
cmd1; cmd2
```

and

```
cmd1 && cmd2
```

is that in the first case, `cmd2` will always execute after `cmd1` has terminated, while in the second case, `cmd2` only executes if `cmd1` terminated with a zero exit status (signalling "success").

With

```
cmd1 & cmd2
```

`cmd1` is started as a background job (an asynchronous task), and `cmd2` is started immediately after starting `cmd1` (the two would run concurrently).

Both `&` and `;` are called "list separators", separating lists of commands. In the [POSIX shell grammar](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10), they are called "separator operators".

Comment: Yes, I know its functionality. Actually I am looking for terminology for semi-colon.

Comment: @SalmanAhmed This was not clear from the question, but I've added it to the answer.

Comment: The bash manual describes them as [control operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-control-operator)

Comment: @glennjackman I'm sure it does. The main thing is that `;` is not an "AND operator".